# How to check if the fragment is visible to user

Tags: android, fragment

### How to check if a fragment is visible to the user in an Android app?

I have an app where the **Home** `activity` has several `fragments`. One of the fragments listens to events from another activity started from **Home** and hence executing a method every time I come back to **Home** from that activity. While what I want is to only trigger those events and have the method executed **if the fragment is visible to the user in the foreground.**

I have tried the following but nothing seemed to work:

1. `isAdded()` and `isVisible()` check - always return `true` as soon as the fragment the created, irrespective of fragment actually visible to the user or not.
2. `getUserVisibleHint()` - this again would return `true` even if I was still in the other activity. Additionally, it is deprecated as well, so even if it worked I would want to look for another solution.

I have come to a dead-end to find an actual working way to check if the fragment is actually visible to the user and not just added to memory.

Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally came across the solution while trying myself:

Simple check for `isResumed()` and it'd only return true if the fragment is in the foreground and resumed state.

Just to be safe, check for `isVisible` which also checks for `isAdded` internally and would reduce the condition, so a simple `if-condition`:

```
if (isVisible() && isResumed()) {
    // perform your action here
}
```

This worked for me!

Comment: Why did you add `isResumed()`? And what if a DialogFragment is shown above the fragment? In this case the fragment is already visible.

Comment: 1. If another fragment or a dialog fragment is above it, the previous fragment wouldn't return true to `isResumed` until the dialog is dismissed and the fragment comes to the foreground.  
2. My use case was returning from other activity back to this fragment instead of any other case like dialog or something else, for which resume status seems to work for me.

Comment: This does not work if the fragment is covered by another fragment

Comment: @RunLoop That's what `isVisible` is for :) experiment before you opinionate it.

Comment: @YashJoshi In my project an activity pushes different fragments onto the stack. If a fragment is covered by another fragment pushed onto the stack after it, isVisible still returns true. I worked around it by implementing code that compares the name of the last fragment pushed onto the stack to that of the fragment I want to check for visibility.

Comment: @RunLoop That's a good idea. I've tried going with fragment ID matching as well in sequences of visibility ambiguity on overlapped fragments. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

When returning from another activity or pause operations use @Yash Joshi method but if you want to check if fragment is visible or not in viewpager then use [setMenuVisibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setMenuVisibility(boolean)) the code example bellow

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    if(menuVisible){
        // fragment is visible.
    } else {
        // fragment is invisible.
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to answer as it's when the visibility is changed. OP is asking to check at everytime